# Workflow for Google Apps script approving correct row via email

Tags: email, workflow, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, rows

I am creating a workflow process with Google Apps script. I have looked at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96URE_-aj-8) for most of the layout.

I built a form in Google Apps script that takes input data from a user. The data is then submitted into rows with `e.parameter` values. That data is then emailed to an approver. The approver has an approve button that they press to change the "Status" column to approved.

**Issue:**
I cant get the data to approve the correct row. I am passing a `row` parameter that is supposed to correspond to the correct row but it isnt working.

Here is my code that submits data to the spreadsheet and once the data has been approved via email. The `DoPost` function runs and approves the row. Can someone Please help! I've been trying to find solutions all day.

```
function sendEmail_(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AuCblud0Ss7BdHA1bXZjYXA0Y0IyekhUQm5vWG02MVE").getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 13);
  range.setValues([
    [e.parameter.LastName, e.parameter.FirstName, e.parameter.DivisionName, e.parameter.EffectiveDate,
    e.parameter.Network, e.parameter.EmployeeNewPosition, e.parameter.DivisionFolder, e.parameter.SpecificIndividual,
    e.parameter.Email, e.parameter.username, e.parameter.who, e.parameter.Banner, "Unapproved"]
  ]);


  var row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  //"https://script.google.com/a/macros/wichitafallstx.gov/s/AKfycbwOgTTGqNsVwnqs-xfqa7TEJWGc_lJZdoyoEoixngKdDemVQuo/exec
  var body = '<form action= <form action = " https://sites.google.com/a/macros/wichitafallstx.gov/s/AKfycbxAOGO6q9ofauf34xlDA9sLG8sUXeZsuvQkDKATOQ/exec" method ="post">' +

    "<b>Last Name:</b>" + e.parameter.LastName + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>First Name:</b>" + e.parameter.FirstName + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Division Name:</b>" + e.parameter.DivisionName + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Effective Date:</b>" + e.parameter.EffectiveDate + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Network:</b>" + e.parameter.Network + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Employee New Position:</b>" + e.parameter.EmployeeNewPosition + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Division Folder:</b>" + e.parameter.DivisionFolder + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Specific Individual:</b>" + e.parameter.SpecificIndividual + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Email:</b>" + e.parameter.Email + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Username:</b>" + e.parameter.username + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>who:</b>" + e.parameter.who + '<br><br>' +
    "<b>Banner:</b>" + e.parameter.Banner +

    '<br />' +
    '<br />' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="row" value=" ' + row + ' "/>' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Approve" onclick="approve()" />' +
    '</form>';

  var owners = SitesApp.getSite("wichitafallstx.gov", "information-systems").getOwners();
  var mail = MailApp.sendEmail(owners.join(","), "test", '', {
    htmlBody: body
  });
}

//handles the payload that is posted back to appscript..from the form that is passed from the form created in send email.
function doPost(e) {
  var r = e.parameter["row"];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AuCblud0Ss7BdHA1bXZjYXA0Y0IyekhUQm5vWG02MVE").getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, 13).getValues();

  sheet.getRange(r, 13).setValue("Approved");

}
```

Comment: _I cant get the data to approve the correct row._ What row _is_ it approving? (e.g. should be 5, approved 4...)

Comment: I imagine you tried without the `hidden` to check if the value realy is the one you want.

Comment: I need it to approve that row of data, even if there has been data submitted to the spreadsheet afterwards. The approver needs to be able to go into their email and click "approve" and it approves only that row. I need some type of unique Identifier but I dont know how to incorporate that in this script. – user2027001 just now

Answer (score 1):

> I am passing a row parameter that is supposed to correspond to the correct row but it isnt working.

It appears that you are passing the row below the one intended.

```
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 13);
  range.setValues([
    [e.parameter.LastName, e.parameter.FirstName, e.parameter.DivisionName, e.parameter.EffectiveDate,
    e.parameter.Network, e.parameter.EmployeeNewPosition, e.parameter.DivisionFolder, e.parameter.SpecificIndividual,
    e.parameter.Email, e.parameter.username, e.parameter.who, e.parameter.Banner, "Unapproved"]
  ]);

// In assignment below 'new' lastRow is the row you just filled 
// in with above and should not include + 1
  var row = sheet.getLastRow()   // no + 1;
```

Comment: It is currently doing that but thats not my intention.I need it to approve that row of data, even if there has been data submitted to the spreadsheet afterwards. The approver needs to be able to go into their email and click "approve" and it approves only that row. I need some type of unique Identifier but I dont know how to incorporate that in this script.